# how to use numpy functions with groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a function that takes a dataframe column and returns a boolean mask based on certain conditions:

```
def is_downtrending(close):
    out = np.full(close.shape, False)

    for i in range(close.shape[0]):
        # if we've had two consecutive red days
        if (close[i] < close[i - 1]) and (close[i - 1] < close[i - 2]):
            out[i] = True
        else:
            out[i] = False

    return out
```

Normally I call it by passing in a column:

```
ohlc['is_downtrending'] = is_downtrending(ohlc['close'])
```

**But how can I make this work using `groupby`?** When I try:

```
df['is_downtrending'] = df.groupby("stock_id").apply(is_downtrending)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3629, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/Documents/code/wolfhound/add_indicators_daily.py", line 29, in <module>
    df['is_downtrending'] = df.groupby("stock_id").apply(is_downtrending)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1423, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1464, in _python_apply_general
    values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 761, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "/home/dan/Documents/code/wolfhound/add_indicators_daily.py", line 11, in is_downtrending
    if (close[i] < close[i - 1]) and (close[i - 1] < close[i - 2]):
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3631, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

When I try passing in the column:

```
df['is_downtrending'] = df.groupby("stock_id").apply(is_downtrending('close'))
```

The error changes to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/Documents/code/wolfhound/add_indicators_daily.py", line 29, in <module>
    df['is_downtrending'] = df.groupby("stock_id").apply(is_downtrending('close'))
  File "/home/dan/Documents/code/wolfhound/add_indicators_daily.py", line 7, in is_downtrending
    out = np.full(close.shape, False)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Here's what the df looks like:

```
         index        date symbol  stock_id  open  high     low  close    volume      vwap
0            0  2021-10-11    BVN        13  7.69  7.98  7.5600   7.61    879710  7.782174
1            1  2021-10-12    BVN        13  7.67  8.08  7.5803   8.02    794436  7.967061
2            2  2021-10-13    BVN        13  8.12  8.36  8.0900   8.16    716012  8.231286
3            3  2021-10-14    BVN        13  8.26  8.29  8.0500   8.28    586091  8.185899
4            4  2021-10-15    BVN        13  8.18  8.44  8.0600   8.44   1278409  8.284539
...        ...         ...    ...       ...   ...   ...     ...    ...       ...       ...
227774  227774  2022-10-04   ERIC     11000  6.27  6.32  6.2400   6.29  14655189  6.280157
227775  227775  2022-10-05   ERIC     11000  6.17  6.31  6.1500   6.29  10569193  6.219965
227776  227776  2022-10-06   ERIC     11000  6.20  6.25  6.1800   6.22   7918812  6.217198
227777  227777  2022-10-07   ERIC     11000  6.17  6.19  6.0800   6.10   9671252  6.135976
227778  227778  2022-10-10   ERIC     11000  6.13  6.15  6.0200   6.04   6310661  6.066256

[227779 rows x 10 columns]
```

I've tried  Code Different's suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
import sqlite3 as sql
import numpy as np

conn = sql.connect('allStockData.db') 

# get everything inside daily_ohlc and add to a dataframe
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from daily_ohlc_init", conn)

df["is_downtrending"] = (
    df["close"]
    .groupby(['stock_id']).diff()      # diff between current close and previous close
    .groupby(['stock_id']).rolling(2)  # consider the diff of the last n days
    .apply(lambda diff: (diff < 0).all())  # true if they are all < 0
).fillna(0)

df.to_sql('daily_ohlc_init_with_indicators', if_exists='replace', con=conn, index=True)
```

Which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/Documents/code/wolfhound/add_indicators_daily.py", line 13, in <module>
    .groupby(['stock_id']).diff()      # diff between current close and previous close
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1922, in groupby
    return SeriesGroupBy(
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 882, in __init__
    grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 882, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'stock_id'
```

And trying Ynjxsjmh suggestion threw the error:

```
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: -1
```

So I changed the code to:

```
    def is_downtrending(close):
        out = np.full(close.shape, False)
    
        for i in close.index:  # <--- changes here
            # if we've had two consecutive red days
            if i > 3:
                if (close[i] < close[i - 1]) and (close[i - 1] < close[i - 2]):
                    out[i] = True
                else:
                    out[i] = False
    
        return out
    
    
    df['is_downtrending'] = df.groupby("stock_id", as_index=False)["close"].transform(is_downtrending)
```

Which gives the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3629, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
      File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2131, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
      File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2140, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
    KeyError: -1
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/Documents/code/wolfhound/add_indicators_daily.py", line 25, in <module>
    df['is_downtrending'] = df.groupby("stock_id", as_index=False)["close"].transform(is_downtrending)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1184, in transform
    return self._transform(
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1642, in _transform
    return self._transform_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1156, in _transform_general
    path, res = self._choose_path(fast_path, slow_path, group)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1208, in _choose_path
    res = slow_path(group)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1201, in <lambda>
    slow_path = lambda group: group.apply(
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 8848, in apply
    return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 733, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 857, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 873, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1202, in <lambda>
    lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs), axis=self.axis
  File "/home/dan/Documents/code/wolfhound/add_indicators_daily.py", line 17, in is_downtrending
    if (close[i] < close[i - 1]) and (close[i - 1] < close[i - 2]):
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1069, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3631, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: -1
```

Comment: Are you sure you can call `is_downtrending(ohlc['close'])` without error? You are locating like `close[i - 1]` while `i-1` could be negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `groupby.transform` and update `Series[idx]` to `Series.iloc[idx]`

```py
def is_downtrending(close):
    out = np.full(close.shape, False)

    for i in range(close.shape[0]):
        # if we've had two consecutive red days
        if (close.iloc[i] < close.iloc[i - 1]) and (close.iloc[i - 1] < close.iloc[i - 2]):  # <--- changes here
            out[i] = True
        else:
            out[i] = False

    return out

def is_downtrending2(close):
    out = np.full(close.shape, False)

    for i in close.index:  # <--- changes here
        # if we've had two consecutive red days
        if (close[i] < close[i - 1]) and (close[i - 1] < close[i - 2]):
            out[i] = True
        else:
            out[i] = False

    return out



df['is_downtrending'] = df.groupby("stock_id", as_index=False)["close"].transform(is_downtrending)
```

Comment: Hey thank you  Ynjxsjmh I've updated the OP with a new error after trying your suggestion

Comment: @A7DC How about the `iloc` solution? For loop the `close.index`, `if i > 3` won't escape all the out of bounds. Say one group index is `4, 5, 6`, you will still get out of bounds for `i-1` since first index is already `4`.

Comment: Can you give an example please? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @A7DC Your example data is divided into two groups: index `0-4` and index `227774-227778`. For group index `227774-227778`. Since `227774` is greater than `3`, so it will do comparison `(close[i] < close[i - 1])` while there doesn't exist index `227773` in this group.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't know how to solve this with code

Answer (score 1):

When you call `df.groupby("...").apply(is_downtrending)`, you are passing a dataframe to the function. Your function does not take a dataframe, hence the error.

You can send only one column into the function, as a Series:

```py
df.groupby("stock_id")["close"].apply(is_downtrending)
```

However, I think your function does not calculate the red day correctly.

If your intention is downtrend = n red days in a row, try this:

```
stock_id = ohlc["stock_id"]
n = 2

df["is_downtrending"] = (
    ohlc["close"]
    .groupby(stock_id).diff()      # diff between current close and previous close
    .groupby(stock_id).rolling(n)  # consider the diff of the last n days
    .apply(lambda diff: (diff < 0).all())  # true if they are all < 0
).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hey mate thank you! I think this is what I'm after, I've tried applying the code to my usecase and I'm getting an error. I've updated the OP with the code. Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You didn't check the index. When `i == 0`, `close[i-1]` and `close[i-2]` result in out-of-bound errors